# How to generate several reports with one button using Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have a Shiny app that generates reports about people. I would like to have a single button that generates all the reports as at the moment I am generating them one by one.

The names of the people is generated from `RV4$data[,input$Map_EndoscopistIn]` and the report takes a bunch of parameters as shown. How can I generate the reports in a loop for each element of the list `RV4$data[,input$Map_EndoscopistIn]` (preferably with element name as part of the generated filename?

```
output$Allreports <- downloadHandler(


k<-RV4$data[,input$Map_EndoscopistIn]
      for ( i in k){


filename = "report.docx",
content = function(file) {

  tempReport <- file.path(tempdir(), "report.Rmd")
  file.copy("report.Rmd", tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)

  # Set up parameters to pass to Rmd document
  params <- list(EndoscopistChooserIn = RV4$data[,input$Map_EndoscopistIn][i],
                 Map_EndoscopistIn=input$Map_EndoscopistIn,
                 BarrEQPerformFinalTable=BarrEQPerformFinalTable(),
                 EndoscopyTypesDonePre=EndoscopyTypesDonePre(),
                 performanceTable=data(),
                 IndicsVsBiopsiesPre=IndicsVsBiopsiesPre(),
                 GRS_perEndoscopist_TablePrep=GRS_perEndoscopist_TablePrep()
  )

  rmarkdown::render(tempReport, output_file = file,
                    params = params,
                    envir = new.env(parent = globalenv())
  )
}
}
  )
```

The attempt above doesn't work.

Comment: The download button is running in the web browser and it can only download a single file. You need to create all the reports in different temp files, then zip them up and return just the single zip file. So the `filename` parameter to `downloadHandler` returns just the name of the zip file. The `content` parameter has the code with a loop to generate all the reports, then to zip them up into the file named in the `filename` parameter.

Comment: This code might point you in the right direction. It is not creating reports, but it does create multiple files and zip them together for download. https://github.com/akoyabio/phenoptrReports/blob/master/inst/spatial_map_viewer_app/server.R#L143

Comment: Maybe an alternative is to just render the reports in the background after a button click, without a download handler. Then just point the user to a location where the files were saved.